# cakephp 4.* cake : The term 'cake' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: php, cakephp, visual-studio-code, path

any help please DB : XAMPP , logiciel : vscode

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ro278.jpg]

cake : The term 'cake' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
At line:1 char:1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Powershell doesn't run commands from the current location, you'd for example have to lower protection by adding the directory to your path environment variable (which I wouldn't recommend). Alternatively you'd use `.\` before the command, to make it clear that you want to run a command in the current directory, ie `.\cake`.

However you should not run `cake` from within the `bin` directory in the first place, you should run it from the root of your application, ie from within your `cakephp` directory, so that you'd use:

```
bin\cake bake
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Console Commands](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/console-commands.html)**
- **[Bake Cookbook > Code Generation with Bake](https://book.cakephp.org/bake/2/en/usage.html)**

Comment: @OmarChakroun You're welcome. Note that I had a typo in my answer, I ment to write `.\cake`, not `.\bin`.